# Use Python to change a print composer layout item's extent in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pyqgis-3

I have a QGIS project and in that project there is a print composer layout titled *mainmap*.  This print composer layout has my desired layout items like a title, scalebar, and legend.  *mainmap* also has a map with the default name *Map 1*.

I can use the Python code below in the Python Console to move the extent of the project canvas to the extent of the QgsRectangle just fine.

```
rect = QgsRectangle(1196381.0,655556.0,1204217.0,660632.0)
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(rect)
canvas.refresh()
```

I would now like to use Python to also change the extent of mainmap/Map 1 in the print composer to the same QgsRectangle referenced in the code above.
I can see the Extent settings in the Item Properties (see the image below) and I can set them manually.  What Python code would I do to set the extents of Map 1 to match the map canvas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the code example below, which will change the extent of the map item with the id `map1` in the layout named `test` to the same extent as the map canvas extent:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("test")
mapItem = layout.itemById('map1')
#make sure that it is a MapItem
if type(mapItem).__name__ == "QgsLayoutItemMap":
    mapItem.setExtent(canvas.extent())
```